# Variable in controller is always undefined in View - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am using es6 AngularJS and has this code declaring a simple variable

```
export default class HomeCtrl {
    constructor() {
        'ngInject';

        this.num = [1,2];
    }
}
```

in the view I just have

```
<span>{{ vm.num === undefined }}</span>
```

but it always says `true`

I am using this config so I am not sure what causing the issue

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    contollerAs: 'vm',
    template: homeView,
  });
```

**UPDATE:**

I found out that it conflict with the AppCtrl that I specify this is my whole config code

```
export default angular.module('app', [
  ngTouch,
  ngSanitize,
  uiRouter,
  animations,
  directives,
  services,
  controllers,
  components,
])
.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      abstract: true,
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      template: appView,
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      contollerAs: 'vm',
      template: homeView,
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}).name;
```

when I use the vm in the homeView.html, the vm that was called was the vm of AppCtrl which is my parent controller

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. [It **works**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-yelr5s?embed=1&file=home/home.controller.js) for me.

Comment: What's `homeView`, an html? Maybe you're not specifying it properly.

Comment: @lealceldeiro I specify it correctly `<span>{{ vm.num === undefined }}</span>` is under the homeView thats why it shows. I dont understand mine not working though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. Angular issue changing my state provider like this fix the issue

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.home', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl as vm',
      template: homeView,
});
```